# Create shadows for a layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[Layout with shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeRxv.jpg)

I would like to create same shadow and layout as shown in above figure i tried http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/ but i am not able to clear those 9 patch lines on top and left side of image

Comment: use `CardView` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Material design, this can be done elegantly using elevation:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    ...
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect" />
```

https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Comment: Technically you are. The card view you showed is Material design.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use Cardview for this.

like below you can show shadow.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"

    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Profile"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profile"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:id="@+id/frag_setting_profile_tv"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        style="@style/textview_primary"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

app:cardElevation  property show below shadow view .